# Google Adwords Conversion Tracking using an iframe form

Tags: javascript, iframe, tracking, google-ads-api

I had a form on my website and after the form was filled in the person would be redirected to a thank you page were i had a generated google script and it tracked it as a conversion.

I am now using an iframe and i have tried doing the same thing, but it is not working. I think it is because the client ID / session ID is not the same.

I am really stuck and could use some advice.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this about an Adwords conversion script or about Google Analytics? I'm asking because your question tag is Adwords, but client ID / session ID is used in Analytics.

Comment: @dorian Hi, yes it's def adwords.

Comment: Where are you using the iframe? Is the form inside an iframe or instead redirecting you are embedding an iframe